# How to insert binary data into sql server using SSMS

Tags: sql-server, image, ssms

Is there a way to insert binary data into sql server directly from SQL Server management studio?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Found the answer:

SQL Server has an "OPENROWSET" command that accepts a filepath.

eg

```
Update myTable
set Image = (
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\image.png', SINGLE_BLOB) test)
where ImageID = 1
```

Source: http://shortfastcode.blogspot.com/2009/12/insert-binary-data-like-images-into-sql.html

Comment: This requires that OPENROWSET is enabled on the server - it is disabled by default.

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Table (field1) VALUES (0xABCDEF)
```

Where `0xABCDEF` is your binary data represented as an hexadecimal sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I found no way to upload/download binary file from SSMS GUI without script.

So I switch to MySQL with Workbench. From their table editor, for a **BLOB** column, in the context menu, there are `Load Value From File...` and `Save Value To File...` options.